# JQuery - how to bind a change() function to a dynamically created <select>?

Tags: jquery

I create  elements on the DOM by JS. The question is, how to assign .change() function for each new created  element ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even nicer than `.live()`, from a performance point of view, is [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  This works in the same way as `.live()`: it uses something called event bubbling, which means that when an event is triggered on a DOM element, that element's parents are all notified of the event.  `delegate`, however, has somewhat nicer syntax and a substantial performance benefit.

```
$('#parentElement').delegate('select.yourSelectClass', 'change', function() {
    // do your processing here
});
```

`#parentElement` can be any selector that matches the common ancestor element of all the `select` elements that you are going to add.  This might be `document.body`, but there will probably be another element in the DOM tree that you can bind to.

`select.yourSelectClass` means that the this handler will only be triggered on select elements with the class `yourSelectClass`.  You could change this selector to use any other jQuery selector syntax as you like.

Answer (score 3):

Let [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) be your friend:

```
$('.yourSelectClass').live('change', function(event){
    // Handle the Change event here.
});
```

Comment: Yah I just saw that. I used .on instead.

Comment: Live has performance issues. It listens to changes in all DOM document while delegate listens only to changes in DOM tree starting from parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `live` function: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

[Use jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). (Version 1.3 or greater)

```
$(".classOfJSCreatedElements").live('change',
function(event){
//do stuff
});
```

If you have to use an older version of jQuery use the [livequery plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)

Source: [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F)